# XML list not enclosed in root element deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

My XML has structure similar to:

```
<rootNode>
   <node/>
   <otherNode/>
   <specificNode>
      nested nodes
   </specificNode>
   <specificNode>
      nested nodes
   </specificNode>
</rootNode>
```

then I have corresponding class:

```
class rootNode
{
   string node;
   string otherNode;
   List<specificNodesClass> specificNodes;
}

class specificNodesClass
{
   //all the specific Node's nested nodes
}
```

How can I deserialize the XML to fullfill rootNode type object?
I've tried :

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(rootNode));
result = (rootNode)serializer.Deserialize(xdocument.CreateReader(ReaderOptions.None));
```

with `[XmlElement("specificNode")]` above the `List<specificNodesClass> specificNodes;`, but I get "Input string was not in a correct format." exception.

Could it be an exception caused by specificNode's nested elements incorrect deserialization?

**Problem was at one of the specificNode's nested nodes, as I suspected. Problem solved! Thank you everybody!**

Comment: your class and members are private. what if you make them public?

Comment: Already tried, did not help.

Comment: and also made members as autoproperties. i.e. node { get;set; }

Answer (score 0):

Decorate class rootNode with [XmlRoot("rootNode")] and decorate the properties of your class appropriately with [XmlElement()]

You could also use

```
public static T DeSerializeObject<T>(string xml)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        XmlSerializer _xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (StringReader _tr = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            using (XmlReader _xr = XmlReader.Create(_tr, new XmlReaderSettings()))
            {
                return (T)_xs.Deserialize(_xr);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to deserialize the XML:

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(rootNode));
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\myXml.xml");//path of xml file
object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
rootNode XmlData = (rootNode)obj;
reader.Close();
```

For more freferences, [Click here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/487571/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part-2)

Comment: If its same, then you would not be decorating the class and its members attributes correctly. Try and follow link correctly.